# hash_pbkdf2 gives no output

Tags: php, hash, passwords, pbkdf2

I'm writing a piece of php code but is does not give me the output i want;

```
function passhash($unhashPass){

if(CRYPT_BLOWFISH != 1) {
       throw new Exception("bcrypt not supported in this installation.);
    }
$salt = "test123";
$password = hash_pbkdf2 ("sha256", $unhashPass, $salt, 1, 20);
echo $password;
return $password;
}
```

When i put an echo statement for unhashpass or salt before the hash it works, but after it does nothing, the whole php script just gives me a white screen.
Can somebody help me :)?

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function `hash_pbkdf2()` will be introduced in PHP version 5.5, so i suspect that your installed PHP version does not yet support this function. Before you call the function, you test whether BCrypt is defined, but the function `hash_pbkdf2()` (password-based-key-derivation-function) has nothing to do with BCrypt.

It is recommended to hash passwords with BCrypt though, in PHP version 5.5 you can do it with `password_hash()` instead. There also exist a [compatibility pack](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat/blob/master/lib/password.php) for earlier versions.

```
// Hash a new password for storing in the database.
// The function automatically generates a cryptographically safe salt.
$hashToStoreInDb = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_BCRYPT);

// Check if the hash of the entered login password, matches the stored hash.
// The salt and the cost factor will be extracted from $existingHashFromDb.
$isPasswordCorrect = password_verify($password, $existingHashFromDb);
```

Comment: Yeah, but the site is running on a server so i cant change anything to the php version, however i will try with the external file. Thank you !

Comment: @user2156757 - The compatibilty pack is probably the best solution for earlier PHP versions.

Comment: those are just external libs i can place in htmldocs right? I might look for one of those then :)

Comment: @user2156757 - Yes it is just one independent php file, just copy it to your project. Then you can call the functions like the example in the answer.